# Remove text from column in sql database

Tags: sql

I need to remove some text from a sql db in a metadata colum that's taking up too much space and isn't necessary.

```
ImageDescription:               Make:NIKON     Model:COOLPIX L26     Orientation:1     XResolution:300     YResolution:300     ResolutionUnit:2     Software:COOLPIX L26    V1.0     DateTime:2013:01:05 05:43:12     YCbCrPositioning:2     ExposureTime:0.04     FNumber:3.2     ExposureProgram:2     ISOSpeedRatings:200     ExifVersion:3836042731,664497658,2489535484,2327246609     DateTimeOriginal:2013:01:05 05:43:12     DateTimeDigitized:2013:01:05 05:43:12     ComponentsConfiguration:185856,59901696,256,1280     CompressedBitsPerPixel:2     ExposureBiasValue:0     MaxApertureValue:3.4     MeteringMode:5     LightSource:0     Flash:24     FocalLength:4.6     UserComment:0,0,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,2105376,16973830,65539,393216,18481972,65541,62128128,18546688,65541,62652416,19398656,65539,131072,33685414,65540,63176704,33685504,65540,223674368,0,19660800,65536,19660800,65536,3640590336,2214648831,202051584,269093902,302910734,403902481,370678312,590419990,975707429,960249139,1077360691,1078877256,927291204,1366118456,1734500183,1295935336,1685092721,1734696056,303104355,404035602,790239791,1110983267,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,3237962595,528640,60817528,33562881,285409553,29687553,16777378,16843013,65793,0,16777216,84148994,151521030,1051402,50528514,84083714,263173,24969472,67109634,554829073,319177009,570909009,2167542897,587768209,365015362,619762002,2188534323,387320329,622467352,690497318,909456426,976828471,1178944579,1246316615,1448432723,1515804759,1717920867,1785292903,1987409011     FlashpixVersion:1687135923,3231872644,1301805154,2554547069     ColorSpace:1     PixelXDimension:640     PixelYDimension:480     FileSource:3     SceneType:1     CustomRendered:0     ExposureMode:0     WhiteBalance:0     DigitalZoomRatio:0     FocalLengthIn35mmFilm:26     SceneCaptureType:0     GainControl:1     Contrast:0     Saturation:0     Sharpness:0     SubjectDistanceRange:0
```

I want to get rid of the Usercomment part of that text.
So far I have this that will remove anything left of the usercomment.

```
UPDATE Document
SET MetaData = LEFT(MetaData, CHARINDEX('UserComment:', MetaData) -1)
WHERE MetaData IS NOT NULL
AND MetaData like '%UserComment:%'
AND DocumentId = '480024'
```

But I just want to get rid of the usercomment and not anything before or after that.

here is a sample of just the UserComment, it seems to not have any spaces.

```
      UserComment:0,0,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,2105376,16973830,65539,393216,18481972,65541,62128128,18546688,65541,62652416,19398656,65539,131072,33685414,65540,63176704,33685504,65540,223674368,0,19660800,65536,19660800,65536,3640590336,2214648831,202051584,269093902,302910734,403902481,370678312,590419990,975707429,960249139,1077360691,1078877256,927291204,1366118456,1734500183,1295935336,1685092721,1734696056,303104355,404035602,790239791,1110983267,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,1667457891,3237962595,528640,60817528,33562881,285409553,29687553,16777378,16843013,65793,0,16777216,84148994,151521030,1051402,50528514,84083714,263173,24969472,67109634,554829073,319177009,570909009,2167542897,587768209,365015362,619762002,2188534323,387320329,622467352,690497318,909456426,976828471,1178944579,1246316615,1448432723,1515804759,1717920867,1785292903,1987409011
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any constant text after the comment (space?) that is not contained in the user comment?

Comment: Yes there's spaces before and after the usercomment block of text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use charindex to find where the user comment start and where it ends

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

After that use Left & Right functions to create the string you want to keep

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx

```
select 
    CHARINDEX('UserComment:', MetaData),
    CHARINDEX(' ', MetaData, CHARINDEX('UserComment:', MetaData)),
    LEFT(aaa, CHARINDEX('UserComment:', MetaData)-1) + RIGHT(MetaData, LEN(MetaData) - CHARINDEX('     ', MetaData, CHARINDEX('UserComment:', MetaData))) 
 from dbo.MetaData
```

Comment: Got an error there. Says the Right function requires 2 arguments

Comment: Taht didn't error. However it didn't remove the usercomment either. lol

Comment: What's happening with that query there is copying everything before the usercomment and putting it back in so it's double.

Comment: are u sure there are no spaces (or a double space) after the "UserComment" ?
Try to select `LEN(MetaData) - ( CHARINDEX(' ', MetaData, CHARINDEX('UserComment:', MetaData) -1)+1))` to know how many chars from the right you are going to get

Comment: the UserComment is a very long string that starts like this `UserComment:0,0,538976288,` and ends with 5 spaces

Comment: run the updated code. I actually created a table with your input and it works for me
the 2 first selects are for debug. you need the 3rd selected field

Comment: Result is too long to post. However the UserComment is still not being stripped out.

Comment: what do u get in the first 2 columns? Do the numbers makes sense?

Comment: I get a 663 and a 0 in the first two columns.

Comment: If I do a character count of the UserComment the length should be 1217 characters

Comment: your string does not end with a space!
0 means we were not able to find the desired space in the expression.

Comment: Hrmm.... here's what the end of the usercomment looks like. There are five spaces before FlashpixVersion.  `UserComment:0,0,538976288,538976288,538976288,538976288,2188534323,387320329,622467352,690497318,909456426,976828471,1178944579,1246316615,1448432723,1515804759,1717920867,1785292903,1987409011     FlashpixVersion:1687135923,3231872644,1301805154,2554547069`

Comment: Figured out it was an tab. `CHAR(9)` solved the issue. Thanks for the help.